# Adding margins to reyclerview items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to create a Comments section to my app and am using a RecyclerView to display the comments. I would like to add a left margin to each RecyclerView item to show the "depth" that the comment is replying at. I have successfully added **padding** to each item viewholder using `viewHolder.itemView.setPadding(depth *30, 0, 0, 0);` but there is no equivalent `setMargin` function.

This is what I have now:

[image]

The red line is where I want to create a margin, for example.

I will need to calculate the margin dynamically as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your item views to be a View within a FrameLayout (or similar), so that adding margin actually accomplishes something. But my recommendation would be to use a `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` to apply *offsets* to each view.

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    int indentation = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.indentation);
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = parent.getChildViewHolder(view);
    outRect.left = indentation * holder.getIndentationLevel();
}
```

This is assuming you have a `dimen` resource for a single level of indentation, and that your ViewHolder has the item's indentation level.

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to do anything else to apply the item offsets to my view? Like do I have to call it from my adapter or will it be called automatically somewhere?

Comment: You have to call `recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration)` at some point... usually at the same time you set your adapter / layoutmanager etc.